# Pages randomly will only load halfway or not at all, still shows as "complete"

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a weird issue.  Randomly, I will get pages that only appear halfway or not at all...as in it will randomly cut off in the middle just because it feels like it.  Here's an example, ironically when I was looking for help with this issue:

[image: Cut off in the middle]

What's curious is that the browser considers its job done, there's no 'circling' done on the tab or any "waiting for connection" it just decides that the page has finished loading and stops.

I'm on a wireless connection to a D-Link DIR-632.  It only seems to have started happening after we got the router, but seeing as it was a vast improvement over the various routers we've had before (which all had really bad connection issues with dropped packets, etc.), I would be really hesitant to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work this one out we will have to work step by step through the connection to the website.

First off, let's start at the browser.

Have you tried using a different browser?  What results do you get from trying Internet Explorer?  Does it do the same?

Also, do you get the same results consistantly, or does the page complete if your refresh the page?

Comment: It depends.  Sometimes if I reload it reloads fine.  Other times it shows up blank or defective again.  Usually if I reload 2-3 times it will finally work correctly.  I will let you know if switching browsers makes things any different, but considering that I use Chrome as my primary browser in multiple places without this issue I believe that if it's misbehaving it's a symptom of a connection issue, not of the browser itself.

Comment: I agree, but trying a different browser may manifest the problem in a slightly different way which may point us in the right direction.

Comment: **nods**  I've been using Firefox since you suggested I change browsers.  I've noticed that although I'm not getting half-opening pages (knock on wood), I'm getting the occasional error about the connection being reset.  Maybe that's a lead?

Comment: OK, next thing to check is the connection between your computer and the internet.  If you can, connect the computer to the router with an Ethernet cable and see if that has an effect on the situation.

Comment: First, I found that while browsing the internet with Firefox today, I was occasionally getting a "Connection reset while page was loading" error. As for connecting directly to the router, that's not really a trivial undertaking, unfortunately. This is a desktop computer, and I don't have a spare Ethernet cable that's long enough to reach all the way to router. In addition, it's been doing these odd connection resets no matter what wireless card I use. I'll be frank with you, I'm pretty sure it _is_ a wireless problem.  What I was hoping that this was indicative of some common wireless issue.

Comment: FWIW, I have had the same problem with a crappy WiFi router--in fact I currently have the problem at my charity's office.